# How to save entered data in php form to a text file (if statements)

Tags: php

I'm struggling with my code because it's a little bit complex than having a form save its data to a text file. I wanted the form to show conditional messages like if an empty form is submitted a `"please enter comment"` will show, if finished is entered it will show that the data is accepted and a `"congratulations"` will appear. If it is any other data, it will simply say that data is received and `"thank you for the comment"` will appear. I was able to do this but for some reason I can't make the entered data from the php file save to the text file. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset ="UTF-8">
        <title>mission_2-02</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="comment">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>

        <?php
            $str = $comment . PHP_EOL;
            $filename="mission_2-02.txt";
            $fp = fopen($filename,"w");

            $comment = $_POST ["comment"];
            if ($comment==""){echo "";}
            else echo $comment . "is accepted <br>";


            if (empty ($comment)) {echo"please enter comment";}
            elseif ($comment=="finished"){echo "congratulations";}
            elseif (!empty($comment)){echo "thank you for the comment";}
            else{fwrite($fp, $str );echo $str ;fclose($fp);}
            
            
            if (file_exists($filename)){
                $lines = file($filename,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
                foreach ($lines as $line){
                    echo $line . "<br>";
                }  
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your HTML markup is invalid. The closing `</head>` must come before the opening `<body>` tag and there should be a space between `meta` and `charset` in `<metacharset ="UTF-8">`

Comment: It looks like the question has nothing to do with MySql

Comment: You are assigning a variable before it has been defined -  `$str = $comment . PHP_EOL;` ~ at that stage it has not been created

Answer (score 1):

A variation on a theme perhaps...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8' />
        <title>mission_2-02</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <input type='text' name='comment' placeholder='comment' />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>

        <?php
            
            $filename='mission_2-02.txt';
            
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST["comment"] ) ){
                
                $output=array();
                $errors=array();
                
                $comment=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'comment', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
                
                
                if( !empty( $comment ) )$output[]=sprintf('Thankyou - your comment "%s" was accepted!', $comment );
                else $errors[]='Please enter a comment!';
                
                if( strtolower( trim( $comment ) )==='finished' )$errors[]='Congratulations';
                
                if( !empty( $errors ) )printf('<pre>%s</pre>',implode( PHP_EOL, $errors ));
                else{
                    file_put_contents( $filename, $comment . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
                    printf('<pre>%s</pre>',implode( PHP_EOL, $output ) );
                }
            }
            
            
            if( file_exists( $filename ) ){
                foreach( file( $filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES ) as $line )printf('%s<br />',$line);
            }

            clearstatcache();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using valid tools for working with PHP and valid formatting for clarity, would help you faster.

1. You can not assign variable before it has been defined (as *ProfessorAbronsius* pointed)
2. You trying to write the file content in the `else` clause which is not reached

compare:

```php
<?php
$filename = "mission_2-02.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename, "w");

$comment = $_POST ["comment"];
$str = $comment . PHP_EOL;
if ($comment == "") {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo $comment . "is accepted <br>";
}


if (empty($comment)) {
    echo "please enter comment";
} elseif ($comment == "finished") {
    echo "congratulations";
} elseif (!empty($comment)) {
    fwrite($fp, $str);
    echo $str;
    fclose($fp);
    echo "thank you for the comment";
} else { // this is unreachable
    fwrite($fp, $str);
    echo $str;
    fclose($fp);
}

echo '<br>Output<br>';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        echo $line . "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

BTW note that this way you override the whole file each time, except appending new values.

Tip: although using `if`/`else` statements without brackets is valid in PHP it's not safe consider code below:

```php
// not safe approach, altough still valid, 
// in this case last echo is OUT of the else statement!
if (1 == 1)
    echo 'equal';
else
    echo 'not equal';
    echo 'something else';

// safe approach
if (1 == 1) {
    echo 'equal';
}
else {
    echo 'not equal';
    echo 'something else';
}

// short valid approach
echo (1 == 1) ? 'equal' : 'not equal';
```